# Microservice - synchronise data access

Tags: c#, microservices, azure

If got a scenario with accounts in any currency.
The account got multiple lines/items for each transaction which adds or removes an amount of the account. Basically similar to a bank account. The requirement is that a user should be able to see the total amount of account.

My scenario includes multiple clients (eventually hundrets) which are updating the account. All of that should be scaleable by microservices.

The crux I'm struggling with, is multiple clients are updating the same account all the time.

How can I synchronise the updateing of the total amount of the account.

Should I just sum all account items on demand?

Should I store the total amount, but how can I update one single record from multiple clients and make sure that it is still in sync?

What is best practise?

I'm using C# in a microsoft azure infrastructure. 
Which components, databases and so on are getting used is still open.

Comment: The best practice is the one that most effectively meets your specific requirements.

Comment: "Use the Queue, Luke". Instead of sharing your resource, serialize the requests into a queue and create snapshots of your data. Take a look into [Microsoft's](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/event-sourcing) view of this and [Martin Fowler's](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) view on this. It may help.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I store the total amount, but how can I update one single record from multiple clients and make sure that it is still in sync?

This is ***caching* strategy**, because it represents **maintaining *a copy of a value* that is derivable** from other persistence.

In general, caching is an optimization that increases performance at the cost of increased complexity.  Caching is well-known as error prone, which is indicative of introduced complexity.  We should not engage in optimization unless we have the way to verify that the optimization is offering business value (such as performance observable by the end-user, lower operating costs, etc...), since optimization will incur cost in complexity of implementation while reducing maintainability and agility.  Further, cached information has to be maintained during modification: this actually reduces performance in some code paths; hence, it is wise to be sure that it is an overall benefit through performance testing.  (Caching can also increase space requirements, which may also adversely affects performance.)

Considering that you have not yet chosen components such as db for persistence; I'd submit that such optimization is premature.

So, design the simplest possible model that works — meaning to use the simple sum query to find sum answers.  Improve it where, when, and *only if* there is a problem.

When starting a project, correctness should be a top consideration.  As you have multiple users accessing and updating the same record simultaneously, your concern for your system's transaction integrity is well placed.

---

Regarding optimization there are lots of possibilities, so when you get that far, consider some alternatives.  For just one example, if the account-balance-changing line items are themselves immutable as in an append -only log, you can post a snapshot of the account totals on regular or as needed intervals, so that a sum query need only sum (the few) line items posted after latest total snapshot.  Since a snapshot over log data never goes out of date, you don't have a synchronization problem.